# Get area bounded by Tkinter canvas lines

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a short code that allows people to freely draw using tkinter, and when they release the mouse button a line is automatically created between the two endpoints of their free draw, thus forming a close loop.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.original = Image.open("C:/Users/elver/Pictures/living.jpg")
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.original)
        self.display = Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.display.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor=NW, tags="IMG")
        self.display.grid(row=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
        self.display.bind('<Button-1>', self.click)
        self.display.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move)
        self.display.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.release)
        self.linelist = []

    def resize(self, event):
        size = (event.width, event.height)
        resized = self.original.resize(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
        self.display.delete("IMG")
        self.display.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor=NW, tags="IMG")

    def click(self, click_event):
        global prev
        prev = click_event
        for x in range(0, len(self.linelist)-1):
            self.display.delete(self.linelist[x])
        self.linelist.clear()
        self.display.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor=NW, tags="IMG")


    def move(self, move_event):
        global Canline
        global prev
        Canline=self.display.create_line(prev.x, prev.y, move_event.x, move_event.y, width=2)
        self.linelist.append(Canline)
        prev = move_event
        #print(len(self.linelist))

    def release(self, release_event):
        global Canline
        Canline=self.display.create_line(self.display.coords(self.linelist[1])[0], self.display.coords(self.linelist[1])[1], \
        self.display.coords(self.linelist[len(self.linelist)-1])[0], self.display.coords(self.linelist[len(self.linelist)-1])[1], width=2)

root =Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

I am now trying to fill in the area bounded by the close loop, but I can't seem to find a way to do that.
I can't find a way to differentiate the area inside the closed loop and the area outside of it.

Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `living.jpg` image to it so others can easily run your code.

Comment: For filling the area, you can replace the group of lines (`create_line()`) by one polygon (`create_polygon()`).

Comment: There's nothing you can do to turn your collection of lines into a filled shape.  However, you can use `.create_polygon()` to make a new filled shape, passing it the coordinates from all of your lines.

Comment: BTW: instead of `self.linelist[len(self.linelist)-1]` you can use `self.linelist[-1]`

Comment: BTW: if you use `class` then you could/should use `self.prev` instead of `global prev`. And `self.Canline` instead of `global Canline`

Comment: BTW: instead of `for x in range(0, len(self.linelist)-1): self.display.delete(self.linelist[x])` you can do `for item in self.linelist: self.display.delete(item)`

Comment: BTW: first element on list has index `[0]` but you use `[1]`

Comment: Thank you acw1668 and especially @furas for your help! As you might have guessed I'm very new to python, and your comments truly nudge me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep points `(event.x, event.y)` on list `self.points` and use this list in `release` to draw filled polygon:

```
create_polygon(self.points)
```

You can even use first and last element from this list to draw closing line - so you don't need to get coordinates from `self.display.coords(self.lines[0])` and `self.display.coords(self.lines[-1])`

```
first = self.points[0]
last  = self.points[-1]

line = self.display.create_line(*first, *last, width=2)
```

---

Working code with many other changes

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- classes ---

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.original = Image.open("Obrazy/images/image-800x600.jpg")
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.original)

        self.display = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.display.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor='nw', tags="IMG")
        self.display.grid(row=0, sticky='news')

        self.display.bind('<Button-1>', self.click)
        self.display.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move)
        self.display.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.release)

        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)

        self.lines = []
        self.points = []

        self.polygon = None

    def resize(self, event):
        size = (event.width, event.height)
        resized = self.original.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)

        # replace image in object instead of deleting and creating object again 
        self.display.itemconfig("IMG", image=self.image)

        #self.display.delete("IMG")
        #self.display.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor='nw', tags="IMG")

        # TODO: recalculate self.points to resize polygon ???

    def click(self, event):
        for item in self.lines:
            self.display.delete(item)

        if self.polygon:
            self.display.delete(self.polygon)
            self.polygon = None

        self.lines.clear()
        self.points.clear()
        #self.lines = []
        #self.points = []

        self.points.append((event.x, event.y))
        self.prev = event

        # ??? I don't know what is this ????
        #self.display.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor='nw', tags="IMG")

    def move(self, event):
        line = self.display.create_line(self.prev.x, self.prev.y, event.x, event.y, width=2)
        self.lines.append(line)

        self.points.append((event.x, event.y))
        self.prev = event

    def release(self, event):
        #first = self.display.coords(self.lines[0])
        #last  = self.display.coords(self.lines[-1]) 

        first = self.points[0]
        last  = self.points[-1]

        line = self.display.create_line(*first, *last, width=2)
        self.lines.append(line)

        self.polygon = self.display.create_polygon(self.points, fill='red', outline='black', width=2)
        # you could delet lines here if you don't need them

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

In this version I use `create_polygon` at start and later I use `coords()` to update points in this polygon. This way I don't need list with lines and don't use `create_line()`.

It displays closing line all time during drawing.

`coords()` needs flat list `[x1, y1, x2, y1, ...]` instead of `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]` so I use `list.extend([x, y])` (`list += [x, y]`) instead of `list.append([x, y])`

I use `fill=""` to have transparent polygon during drawing and in `release()` I use `configitem()` to change it to `fill="red"`

```
def click(self, event):
    # `coords()` needs flat list [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...] instead of [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]
    # so I use `list.extend(other_list)` (`list += other_list`) instead of `list.append(other_list)
    self.points = [event.x, event.y]

    # at start there is no polygon on screen so there is nothing to delete
    if self.polygon:
        self.display.delete(self.polygon)

    # polygon can be created with one point so I can do it here - I don't have to do it in `move` like with `create_line`
    # (BTW: `fill=""` creates transparent polygon)
    self.polygon = self.display.create_polygon(self.points, fill='', outline='black', width=2)

def move(self, event):
    # `coords()` needs flat list [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...] instead of [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]
    # so I use `list.extend(other_list)` (`list += other_list`) instead of `list.append(other_list)
    self.points += [event.x, event.y]

    # update existing polygon
    self.display.coords(self.polygon, self.points)

def release(self, event):
    # change fill color at the end
    self.display.itemconfig(self.polygon, fill='red')
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I realized that `create_line` can get more then two points and create many lines at once so I use it in this version.

I add points to list and use `coords()` to update points in existing line. This way I have only one line (with many points - polygon without closing line) and I don't need list with lines.

```
def click(self, event):
    # `coords()` needs flat list [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...] instead of [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]
    # so I use `list.extend(other_list)` (`list += other_list`) instead of `list.append(other_list)
    self.points = [event.x, event.y]

    # at start there is no polygon on screen so there is nothing to delete
    if self.polygon:
        self.display.delete(self.polygon)
        self.polygon = None  # I need it in `move()`

    # `create_line()` needs at least two points so I cann't create it here.
    # I have to create it in `move()` when I will have two points

def move(self, event):
    # `coords()` needs flat list [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...] instead of [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]
    # so I use `list.extend(other_list)` (`list += other_list`) instead of `list.append(other_list)
    self.points += [event.x, event.y]

    if not self.polygon:
        # create line if not exists - now `self.points` have two points
        self.polygon = self.display.create_line(self.points, width=2)
    else:
        # update existing line 
        self.display.coords(self.polygon, self.points)

def release(self, event):
    # replace line with polygon to close it and fill it (BTW: `fill=""`if you want transparent polygon)
    self.display.delete(self.polygon)
    self.polygon = self.display.create_polygon(self.points, width=2, fill='red', outline='black')
```

---

Full code for **EDIT 1**

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- classes ---

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.original = Image.open("image.jpg")
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.original)

        self.display = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.display.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor='nw', tags="IMG")
        self.display.grid(row=0, sticky='news')

        self.display.bind('<Button-1>', self.click)
        self.display.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move)
        self.display.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.release)

        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)

        self.points = []
        self.polygon = None

    def resize(self, event):
        size = (event.width, event.height)
        resized = self.original.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)

        # replace image in object instead of deleting and creating object again 
        self.display.itemconfig("IMG", image=self.image)

        # TODO: recalculate self.points to resize polygon ???

    def click(self, event):
        # `coords()` needs flat list [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...] instead of [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]
        # so I use `list.extend(other_list)` (`list += other_list`) instead of `list.append(other_list)
        self.points = [event.x, event.y]

        # at start there is no polygon on screen so there is nothing to delete
        if self.polygon:
            self.display.delete(self.polygon)

        # polygon can be created with one point so I can do it here - I don't have to do it in `move` like with `create_line`
        # (BTW: `fill=""` creates transparent polygon)
        self.polygon = self.display.create_polygon(self.points, fill='', outline='black', width=2)

    def move(self, event):
        # `coords()` needs flat list [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...] instead of [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]
        # so I use `list.extend(other_list)` (`list += other_list`) instead of `list.append(other_list)
        self.points += [event.x, event.y]

        # update existing polygon
        self.display.coords(self.polygon, self.points)

    def release(self, event):
        # change fill color at the end
        self.display.itemconfig(self.polygon, fill='red')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Full code for **EDIT 2**

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- classes ---

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.original = Image.open("image.jpg")
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.original)

        self.display = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.display.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image, anchor='nw', tags="IMG")
        self.display.grid(row=0, sticky='news')

        self.display.bind('<Button-1>', self.click)
        self.display.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move)
        self.display.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.release)

        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)

        self.points = []
        self.polygon = None

    def resize(self, event):
        size = (event.width, event.height)
        resized = self.original.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)

        # replace image in object instead of deleting and creating object again 
        self.display.itemconfig("IMG", image=self.image)

        # TODO: recalculate self.points to resize polygon ???

    def click(self, event):
        # `coords()` needs flat list [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...] instead of [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]
        # so I use `list.extend(other_list)` (`list += other_list`) instead of `list.append(other_list)
        self.points = [event.x, event.y]

        # at start there is no polygon on screen so there is nothing to delete
        if self.polygon:
            self.display.delete(self.polygon)
            self.polygon = None  # I need it in `move()`

        # `create_line()` needs at least two points so I cann't create it here.
        # I have to create it in `move()` when I will have two points

    def move(self, event):
        # `coords()` needs flat list [x1, y1, x2, y2, ...] instead of [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ...]
        # so I use `list.extend(other_list)` (`list += other_list`) instead of `list.append(other_list)
        self.points += [event.x, event.y]

        if not self.polygon:
            # create line if not exists - now `self.points` have two points
            self.polygon = self.display.create_line(self.points, width=2)
        else:
            # update existing line 
            self.display.coords(self.polygon, self.points)

    def release(self, event):
        # replace line with polygon to close it and fill it (BTW: `fill=""`if you want transparent polygon)
        self.display.delete(self.polygon)
        self.polygon = self.display.create_polygon(self.points, width=2, fill='red', outline='black')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks for taking the time to explain where and why you made changes to my code, I learned more in 5 minutes with your post than in 2 hours of scouring the internet by myself

Comment: BTW: I didn't test it but maybe instead of lines it can be done with `polygon` and `itemconfig()` which adds new point to polygon (or rather replace all points with new `self.points`).

Comment: I added two new version. First uses `create_polygon()` at start and later `coords()` to add new point to existing polygon. Second uses `create_line()` at start and later `coords()` to add new point to existing line, and finally it remove this line (with many points) and use `create_polygon()`.